# Select string from QComboBox and insert ID into SQLite db

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a simple form containing a combobox and a button "Save". The drop-down list of the combobox displays: "Choose color", "Red", "Green", "Blue". The "Save" button saves the user's choice from the combobox into an underlying database table, `tbl_palette`.

I also have a lookup table, `tlkp_colors`, which contains  a list of colors and their respective ids. I use this lookup table to populate the combo box.

The complete code of this oversimplified example is shown below (it can be run as is):

```py
import sys
import os.path
import sqlite3

######### Qt DESIGNER AUTO GENERATED CODE ##########

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(407, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 201, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 101, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 407, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))

######### END OF AUTO GENERATED CODE ###############

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DB_NAME = 'test.db'
target_db = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, DB_NAME)

class Database:

    def __init__(self):
        # create database 'test.db', add schema, then close it
        cnn = sqlite3.connect(target_db)
        c = cnn.cursor()
        c.executescript("""
                            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tlkp_colors;
                            CREATE TABLE tlkp_colors
                            (
                                color_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                color_name TEXT
                            );

                            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_palette;
                            CREATE TABLE tbl_palette
                            (
                                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                color NUMBER
                            );

                            INSERT INTO tlkp_colors VALUES (0, 'Choose color');
                            INSERT INTO tlkp_colors VALUES (10, 'Red');
                            INSERT INTO tlkp_colors VALUES (20, 'Green');
                            INSERT INTO tlkp_colors VALUES (30, 'Blue');
                        """)
        cnn.commit()
        cnn.close()

    def save(self, your_choice):
        data_tuple = (your_choice,)
        sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO tbl_palette (color) VALUES (?)"""
        db = sqlite3.connect(target_db)
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute(sqlite_insert_query, data_tuple )
        db.commit()
        db.close()    

    def close_db(self):
        target_db.close()

def populate_cbo_from_tlkp_table():
    cnn = sqlite3.connect(target_db)
    c = cnn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT color_name FROM tlkp_colors")
    list_of_strings = [item[0] for item in c.fetchall()]
    cnn.commit()
    cnn.close()
    return  list_of_strings


# comment the following line after the first run (db created already)
db = Database()    # create a new instance Database

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

ui.comboBox.addItems(populate_cbo_from_tlkp_table())
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : db.save(ui.comboBox.currentIndex()))

MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I click on the "Save" button, I want the id of the color to be saved in the underlying table `tbl_palette`, not the color itself - i.e. I want `10` NOT `"Red"`.

I would be very thankful if you could explain how to change the code to do just that. I have searched online, but nothing I have seen so far helped me to solve my problem. I am new to Qt Designer and it seems that I am missing something.

Comment: Fetch `(color_name, color_id)` from the table and use [addItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItem) in a for-loop to populate the combo. The `color_id` can then be retrieved from the combo with [currentData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop).

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code according to ekhumoro's suggestion:

I replaced

```
def populate_cbo_from_tlkp_table():
    cnn = sqlite3.connect(target_db)
    c = cnn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT color_name FROM tlkp_colors")
    list_of_strings = [item[0] for item in c.fetchall()]
    cnn.commit()
    cnn.close()
    return  list_of_strings
```

with

```
def populate_cbo_from_tlkp_table():
    cnn = sqlite3.connect(target_db)
    c = cnn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT color_name, color_id FROM tlkp_colors")
    rows = c.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        ui.comboBox.addItem(str(row[0]), row[1])
        print(row)

    cnn.commit()
    cnn.close()
```

and

```
ui.comboBox.addItems(populate_cbo_from_tlkp_table())
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : db.save(ui.comboBox.currentIndex()))
```

with

```
populate_cbo_from_tlkp_table()
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : db.save(ui.comboBox.currentData()))
```

Now it does exactly what I want it to do.